# How to create static breadcrumb

Tags: 8, breadcrumbs

I've created a breadcumb using this and I've created one. But I would like to create breadcrumb for each page. I've 3 forms, above the form I need to set the progress of the form in the form of breadcrumb,

Drupal 7

```
$breadcrumb[] = l('hi', '/hi');
drupal_set_breadcrumb($breadcrumb);
```

In drupal 8 I've tried to use

```
$b = new Breadcrumb();
$breadcrumb[] = Link::createFromRoute(t('Home'), '<front>');
return $b->setLinks($new_breadcrumbs);
```

But this is not working... 
how we can show that and where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There is a block in drupal 8 for displaying breadcrumb on your pages.
First set visibility of that block on the pages you want to show breadcrumbs.

Then in template_preprocess_breadcrumb in your theme's .theme file you can change the breadcrumbs variables.

For additional functionality you can create breadcrumb.html.twig file in templates folder of your theme.

Comment: Is this the best way to create a simple static breadcrumb?

Comment: For creating static breadcrumb set your breadcrumb variable in template_preprocess_breadcrumb.

Comment: I want it above a form